# Can I access UI components of multiple applications while testing with UIautomator?

Tags: android, testing, android-uiautomator

I am working on testing on Android application with UIautomator. As far as I saw with UIautomatorviewer, I could get to know all ids of UI components in the screen shot. Does that mean I can access the UI component even if a target application call another application. For example, PhotoStream app calls Gallery app when certain button is pressed and would receive ouput from Gallery app. I want to implement testing code which automatically pushes a button in Gallery app if UIautomator provide an API to access an UI component in another app which is called. Does UIautomator API provides such thing?

Answer (score 0):

using UiAutomator you can access any app that is visible on the screen. you don't need any extra API's